# api calls with user id's in a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code that does an api call and writes it into a google sheet. I would like to have a range where I can have several id's and run the calls after each other so I don't have to do the calls one by one and change the id manually.

There is a spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r385734S1DR2I5bWBr1lob-tyiAaCt844mt2HlOt7lc/edit#gid=0) which has the range and an output sheet.

And the code I have been using so far is this

```
function callNumbers() {
   
   // include the API Key
const API_KEY = 'xyz';
 
// set the endpoint
const url = 'https://www.example.com/wp-json/armember/v1/member_details?arm_api_key=xyz&user_id=19&metakeys=country,checkbox_vgc5x';
 
// call the API
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + '&api_key=' + API_KEY);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
   
  var fact = response.getContentText();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue([fact]);
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result when your provided Spreadsheet is used, how about the following modified scripts?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, all requests are run with the fetchAll method.

```js
function callNumbers1() {
  const API_KEY = 'xyz';
  const srcSheetName = "Range of Id's";
  const dstSheetName = "user data output";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const ids = srcSheet.getRange("A1:A" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const reqs = ids.map(([id]) => ({ url: `https://###/wp-json/armember/v1/member_details?arm_api_key=xyz&user_id=${id}19&metakeys=country,checkbox_vgc5x&api_key=${API_KEY}`, muteHttpExceptions: true }));
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs);
  const dstValues = res.map(r => [r.getResponseCode() == 200 ? r.getContentText() : null]);
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, dstValues.length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the IDs are retrieved from column "A" of the source sheet. And, the retrieved values are put into column "A" of the destination sheet.

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, each request is run in a loop.

```js
function callNumbers2() {
  const API_KEY = 'xyz';
  const srcSheetName = "Range of Id's";
  const dstSheetName = "user data output";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const ids = srcSheet.getRange("A1:A" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const dstValues = ids.map(([id]) => {
    const url = `https://###/wp-json/armember/v1/member_details?arm_api_key=xyz&user_id=${id}19&metakeys=country,checkbox_vgc5x&api_key=${API_KEY}`;
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
    return [res.getResponseCode() == 200 ? res.getContentText() : null];
  });
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, dstValues.length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample, it supposes that your showing script for requesting the endpoint works. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the output I was looking for. Both works great so which would you recommend that I use?

Comment: @Mee Thank you for replying. I think that I would like to recommend the 1st pattern because all requests are run with the asynchronous process. If pattern 1 works, I think that the processing speed is high. But, I'm worried that if there are a lot of IDs, an error might occur because of many concurrent requests. In that case, please test the 2nd pattern. The 2nd pattern runs each request in a loop.

Comment: Great thank you very much for your answer. You have been super helpful!